# Product of exponentials formula for robot

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

From WiKi: [Product of exponentials formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_exponentials_formula) is:

$$g_{st}=e^{\hat{\xi}_1\theta_1}e^{\hat{\xi}_2\theta_2}...e^{\hat{\xi}_n\theta_n}$$

where $g_{st}\in SE(3)$,and $\xi_i$ is twist vector $\in {se}(3)$.

My question is: for programming convenient, can i use

$$g_{st}=e^{\hat{\xi}_1\theta_1+\hat{\xi}_2\theta_2+...+\hat{\xi}_n\theta_n}$$

to avoid the matrix product. If cannot, why?

I think the answer is yes, because $\hat{\xi}_1\theta_1+...+\hat{\xi}_n\theta_n$ is still in Lie algebra $se(3)$. But what is its physical explanation?

Comment: No, there are Lie brackets terms coming from $\xi_i$ does not commute with $\xi_j$.  See, for example, [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: @user10354138 I see, you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO, follows user10354138 comment, $\xi_j$ doesn't commute.